# Passing variable to a static function inside subclass

Tags: php, class

I have a class with a variable $x that I want to use in a static function on his subclass.

```
class people{
 protected $x;
  function __constructor(){
   $this->x = 'cool';
  }
 }

class person extended people {
 function static status() {
    'Here I want to use the x variable. I tried $this->x,parent::x..';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This obviously is not possible, since there is no object referred to inside a static method. That is the whole point of a static method: to be able to use it independent of an instantiated object. But without such object you obviously do not have a property `$x`...

There are a few alternatives, which one you chose depends on your situation:

1. you can hand over the value as an explicit argument (so static `function status($x)`), *if* you have access to the property of an instantiated object of class `people`.
2. you can declare the property as `static const` inside the class. In that case you obviously do have access from within a static class method. However it obviously is a constant that can be initialized, but which can not change its value over time.
3. you can design that property *outside* the class. Yes, this is obvious and changes the point of the class design. But since you already try to use a static method chances are that this method should not depend on any instantiated object at all...

In general one can say that the issue you ran into demonstrates that your class design is not conclusive, does not really make sense in itself in its current state. You will have to redesign the class (or maybe a bigger architecture).

Start by asking yourself a question: "*why* do you want to make the method `status()` static at all?"

Comment: Thank you, useful info, now I know it doesn't make sense keep having the function static.